# c#: I want to use a path directory in my feval command

Tags: c#, matlab

Hi is it possible to use such a path:

```
string var1 = @"cd S:\folder\test.txt";
```

instead

```
string var1 = "test.txt";
```

in my code?

At the moment i use this way/solution:

```
string var1 = "test.txt";         
matlab.Feval("function", 1, out result, var1);
```

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: `cd S:\folder\test.txt` is neither valid path in any case nor valid command. What is it supposed to perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all that's a command since it includes DOS command `cd` and not a actual path. It should actually be below  if you intend it to be a path

```
string var1 = @"S:\folder\test.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a file using its absolute path, just put this absolute path in your variable:

```
string var1 = @"S:\folder\test.txt";
```

There is no need to change the current working directory.